# Cleaver (PhoneGap / Cordova as component) not working in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I tried to use Cleaver, that is PhoneGap / Cordova as a component of an existing iOS application. I followed [this step by step guide](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios/blob/master/guides/How%20to%20Use%20Cordova%20as%20a%20Component.md) twice, without success.

My application can easily instantiate a web view, and i can pass content to it using the `stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring` method, but as soon as i try to access PhoneGap API (`navigator.compass, navigator.network, ...`), nothing seems to work. `console.log(navigator)` shows no sign of Cordova objects (`console.log` does not output anything is Xcode, i'm using http://debug.phonegap.com/). The `deviceready` event is not triggered either.

In my html file, i include PhoneGap js file `cordova-1.7.0rc1.js` which i copied from another project (since `/www` folder is missing when you use PhoneGap as a component).

My `ViewController.h` imports `<Cordova/CDVViewController.h>`.
Here my `ViewController.m`

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  CordovaComponent
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){
    CDVViewController *cdvViewController ;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)pushPhoneGap:(id)sender {

    cdvViewController = [[CDVViewController alloc] init];
    cdvViewController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
    cdvViewController.startPage = @"index.html";
    cdvViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    cdvViewController.webView.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:cdvViewController animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setTitle:@"Push PhoneGap view" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(pushPhoneGap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(60, 50, 200., 50.);
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *jsReturn = [cdvViewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"setArray([1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 1]);"];
    NSLog(jsReturn);
}

@end
```

Do you have an idea of what's happening ? Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after many hours of trying to solve this issue, I finally found what was going wrong.
This is the line that messed things up:

```
cdvViewController.webView.delegate = self;
```

You can't just override the delegate of the view controllers's web view. The original delegate has instantiation code which enables PhoneGap to run. Don't override it and everything will be fine !

Comment: Hi, then if this line is not added,  the webViewDidFinishLoad function cannot be fired?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get notified about webview events without breaking Cordova you could try something like this:

```
@interface WrappingWebViewDelegate : NSObject <UIWebViewDelegate>
    @property (nonatomic,retain) id<UIWebViewDelegate> wrappedDelegate;
@end


@implementation WrappingWebViewDelegate
    - (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView {
        [self.wrappedDelegate webViewDidStartLoad: theWebView];
        // your code
    }

    // implement all other delegate methods and forward them to the wrapped delegate
    [...]
@end
```

Usage like this:

```
cdvViewController = [[CDVViewController alloc] init];
WrappingWebViewDelegate wrappingDelegate = [[WrappingWebViewDelegate alloc] init];
wrappingDelegate.wrappedDelegate = cdvViewController.webView.delegate;
cdvViewController.webView.delegate = wrappingDelegate;
```

I haven't tested this, so you should be careful.